# Как узнать DEBUG порт приложения Java из вызываемого кода?

Tags: java

Есть приложение, написанное на Java 11, которое запускается с указанным DEBUG портом. Нужно внутри этого приложения узнать свой собственный DEBUG порт и произвести какие-нибудь действия с ним (например, передать по сети). Есть какой-то простой способ? (Желательно платформо-независимый)

Comment: `DEBUG` задается через аргумент приложения?

Comment: Стандартным способом: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5050`. Наверное, это больше относится к аргументам JVM.